# Need assistance with using memory stream as input for TiffBitmap decoder

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, tiff

I am writing a image viewer in C# and WPF for TIFF images stored in a SQL Server database **image** column. I have coded the retrieval of the images into a memory stream using a GetBytes loop and that works. What is not working is creating a TiffBitmapDecoder from the memory stream and using that as the BitmapSource for a WPF/XAML Image control. Here is my function to return the BitmapSource with the memory stream as input:

```
namespace ViewDBImages
{
    public static class Utility
    {
        public static BitmapSource StreamToImage(MemoryStream imageMem)
        {
            //
            // Decode the Memory Stream argument into a Bitmap with TIFF format
            // First we have to set the Stream seek location to the origin
            //
            imageMem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            //
            // Decode the stream into a TiffBitmap and return it as the image source
            //
            TiffBitmapDecoder decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(imageMem, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand);
            BitmapSource source = decoder.Frames[0];
            return source;
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the images are being set as the source for the image control, because I can see the scroll bars changing as they are retrieved, but they are not visible. I also see that the position of the memory stream is "8" after this function finishes, but the size of the stream is 63,083 bytes.

To help debug this, I copied the memory stream to a TIFF file and used that as the stream input for the decoder. The images are displayed correctly that way. So I suspect there must be some kind of control information that is available when the image is stored as a file, but is not found in the memory stream.  Here is that code:

```
namespace ViewDBImages
{
    public static class Utility
    {
        public static BitmapSource StreamToImage(MemoryStream imageMem)
        {
            //
            // Copy the Memory Stream argument into a filestream and save as a TIF file
            // First we have to set the Stream seek location to the origin
            //
            imageMem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            FileStream imageFile = new FileStream(@"C:\Image Test\Testfile.tif", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            imageMem.CopyTo(imageFile);
            //
            // Decode the file to a TiffBitmap and return it as the image source
            //
            TiffBitmapDecoder decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(imageFile, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnDemand);
            BitmapSource source = decoder.Frames[0];
            return source;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` to make the decoder immediately load the bitmap:

```
var decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(
    imageMem, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
return source = decoder.Frames[0];
```

As a note, you could also directly create a BitmapFrame from a stream. The appropriate decoder is chosen automatically.

```
return BitmapFrame.Create(
    imageMem, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad)
```

Comment: That was the solution, @Clemens.  Thank you for that and for the tips.